# Nested Azure Logic Apps using the same Schema Body type

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I´m splitting a large Workflow logic into different nested logic apps using the same Request Body JSON Schema, which represents a very large entity.
The problem I´m having is that in the designer, when i select a Logic app to be called, I have to specified every single property of the json schema one by one, which is also error prone as some of the properties have similar names.
Is there a way to send the complete body of the current logic app to the nested logic app?

Answer (score 0):

I pass { "data": "@triggerBody()" } onto the child workflow for simplicity.

Yes it does add the need to insert 'data.' before each child workflow reference of a parent schema property but it's saved me a lot of typing!